# How to get all vertices of all outgoing edges from a vertex scala gremlin

Tags: scala, graph-databases, titan, gremlin, gremlin-server

I need to get all list of vertices label of all outgoing egdes from a vertex using scala gremlin.

My code looks like below,

```
val names :ListBuffer[String] = ListBuffer()
val toList: List[Vertex] = graph.V().hasLabel(100).outE().outV().toList()
for(vertex <- toList){
      names  += vertex.label()
    }
```

Its returning the same label name for all vertex
Eg :
Vertex A is having outE to B,C,D . It returns the label of A.
Output:

```
ListBuffer(100, 100, 100)
```

Anything am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you asking for the wrong vertex in the end. Honestly, I often make the same mistake. Maybe this is the traversal you looking for:

```
graph.V().hasLabel(100).outE().inV().label().toList()
```

If you like me and often get confused by `inV()` and `outV()` you can use `otherV` which gets the opposite vertex. Like so:

```
graph.V().hasLabel(100).outE().otherV().label().toList()
```

**Finally** you can even shorten your traversal by not explicitly stating the edge part:

```
graph.V().hasLabel(100).out().label().toList()
```

By using `out()` instead of `outE()` you don't need to specify you want the vertex, `out()` gets you the vertex directly.

Comment: Thanks.Its working perfectly. Also i have 1 more related to drop edge. my query looks like this. `graph.V().hasLabel(100).otherV().hasLabel(100).outE().drop()` . I need to delete the edge  between two given vertices. Looks like its wrong.

Comment: You can't use `otherV()` when you don't first specify you explicitly going over an edge with `inE()` or outE(). I think what you might be looking for is: `graph.V().hasLabel(100).outE().drop().iterate()`. You have to iterate over it at the end.

Comment: Is it possible to get the edge property value in single query, Like given vertex A  has edges to B,C,D with some property value. If Vertex A is given, i need to get the edge property value and vertex label in a set or map

Comment: `graph.V().hasLabel(100).outE().drop().iterate()` Will this drop all the outgoing edges from V(100) ? I need to drop only the edge between two vertices A-->B . Eg . In Case , A--> B , A-->C ,A--D input will be A and B so delete the edge between that only

Comment: Are A, B, and C properties on the vertices ? How do you identify a vertex to be A, B, or C ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Assume A,B,C are labels of vertices and it has edges A-->B , A-->C .. Its Edges having some property. When A is given then it should give me set or map . Eg,[(B,10)(C,20)] or  something like this.

Comment: @Gopi I think you should start a new question rather than asking more questions in the comments here.